# Objective-C: How do I keep track of objects? (getByID)?

Tags: objective-c, reference, cocos2d-iphone, factory

I am confused on how to access objects after I create them, as well as how the scope on these objects work.

I am creating an ios game in which I have a class Monster which extends CCSprite generates a new monster every second or so, and these monsters travel from one side of the screen to the other side, then should be deleted.

I need to be able to access all the monsters currently on the screen, and I want to make sure the monsters off screen are properly disposed of.

Is there an existing method like getSpriteByID()? If not, how do I go about implementing something like that?

Monster.h:

```
#import "CCSprite.h"

@interface Monster : CCSprite

@property (nonatomic, readonly) int instance_id;

@end
```

Monster.m:

```
#import "Monster.h"

static int global_id = 0;

@implementation Monster:CCSprite



-(id) init{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        _instance_id = global_id;
        global_id++;
    }
    return self;
}
-(id) initWithTexture:(CCTexture *)texture rect:(CGRect)rect{
    self = [super initWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
    if(self)
    {
        _instance_id  = global_id;
        global_id++;

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The generating function:

```
- (void)generateTerrain:(CCTime)dt {

    Monster *monster =  [Monster spriteWithImageNamed:@"monster.png"];

    int i = monster.instance_id;

    NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
    CCLOG(@"MonsterID @ %@",myNewString);


    int randomY = (arc4random() % 4) + 1;

    if (randomY == 1)
    {
        monster.position = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + 20, pos1);
    }
    else if (randomY == 2)
    {
        monster.position = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + 20, pos2);
    }
    else if (randomY == 3)
    {
        monster.position = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + 20, pos3);
    }
    else if (randomY == 4)
    {
        monster.position = CGPointMake(self.contentSize.width + 20, pos4);
    }

    // 2
    [self addChild:monster];


    // 3
    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int randomDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    // 4
    CCAction *actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:randomDuration position:CGPointMake(-monster.contentSize.width/2, monster.position.y)];
    CCAction *actionRemove = [CCActionRemove action];
    [monster runAction:[CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[actionMove,actionRemove]]];

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with cocos2d but I guess there's a way to access children of self - like self.subviews. If so, you can get the list of child(monster) and take some action. If there's no way, you have manage the children with your own array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would store all of your monsters in an array.

I'm guessing you're relatively new to cocos2d, so in terms of "properly disposing of your monsters" I would recommend turning on ARC. I would highly recommend just google searching a tutorial for turning on ARC with Cocos2d.

For now though, I'll give you a simple solution that should work.

```
NSMutableArray *monstersArray;

@implementation

- (void)generateTerrain:(CCTime)dt {

    Monster *monster =  [Monster spriteWithImageNamed:@"monster.png"];
    monstersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ...
    [self addChild:monster]
    [monstersArray addObject:monster];
}

// Use this (called 60 fps) to remove a monster
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta {
    for (int i = 0; i < monstersArray.count; i++) {
        Monster *monster = monstersArray[i];
        if (monster.position.x < 0) {
        [self removeMonsterFromArray:monster]
    }
}

// Method to remove monsters, just call this, for example, if a monster is off the screen (it's position in x is less than 0 or something
- (void)removeMonsterFromArray:monster {
    [self removeChild:monster]
}
```

Comment: This may not be the cleanest solution as I'm rusty on cocos2d-v2